# Reviewing possible firebase security holes

Tags: firebase, security, firebase-security

I have an application going to production soon and I would like to make sure I considered all the security issues with firebase and ensure proper firewall rules.

My current list:

- Is someone able to query/read our records?
- Is someone able to modify our existing records?
- Can someone totally spam, fill our DB? Make our current valid records hard to use, filter
- Was a read/write simulation performed on each collection and necessary auth/firewall rules are in place?
- Do we have periodic backup of our records outside of Firebase?
- Who has access to our FB account? Every account has a 2FA in place?

What else would you recommend to check? E.g, the exact domain origin is important to setup right? Etc.

Thx